# Ubuntu - Error Coping Folders with a Space at the end of the Folder Error

Tags: ubuntu, vsftpd

Hello Mighty Keyboard warriors. I have a problem that is kinda of killing me. The Situation:

- vsftpd server with the Following config File (http://pastebin.com/8AVZ9WGK)
- home/user with default permisions
- file.sh script that does the following:

  1. Downloads a HTML web and extract Link to a File.
  2. For each Line of the creates a directory and downloads a N number of images into the following directory.

My Problem: The Files are accesible via FTP over windows with Windows, login with localUser. I can copy Single Files or even multiple files within the same folder. But when I try to copy a folder with all the content in it. N files happends the following: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cHjlJ.jpg.

If I try for the Filezilla i get the following error:

```
Command: LIST
Response:   150 Here comes the directory listing.
Response:   226 Directory send OK.
Status: Directory listing successful
Status: Retrieving directory listing...
Command:    CWD FolderName completa
Response:   550 Failed to change directory.
Error:  Failed to retrieve directory listing
```

#### Edit 1

ls -lat main directory

```
drwxrwxrwx   3 eco01 eco01 4096 Oct  7 14:57 .
drwxrwxr-x 130 eco01 eco01 4096 Oct  7 12:44 FolderName 
-rwxrwxrwx   1 eco01 eco01 1577 Oct  7 12:32 getM.sh
drwxrwxrwx  21 eco01 eco01 4096 Oct  7 11:47 ..
```

ls -lat inside directory

```
drwxrwxr-x   2 eco01 eco01  4096 Oct  7 12:44 Folder 585
drwxrwxr-x   2 eco01 eco01  4096 Oct  7 12:44 Folder 601
drwxrwxr-x   2 eco01 eco01  4096 Oct  7 12:44 Folder 589
drwxrwxr-x   2 eco01 eco01  4096 Oct  7 12:44 Folder 566
drwxrwxr-x   2 eco01 eco01  4096 Oct  7 12:44 Folder 588
drwxrwxr-x   2 eco01 eco01  4096 Oct  7 12:44 Folder 586
drwxrwxr-x   2 eco01 eco01  4096 Oct  7 12:44 Folder 587
```

Comment: Can you cd into the file's directory in terminal and type `ls -lat`?

Comment: Updated the post

Comment: Try a `cp -rfv sourceFolder destinationFolder`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some millions of downloads and test. I Found it. The Matter:

In the Script I "cut" the name of file from a Character ("&").

```
 nameCap=${nameCap%%&*}
```

What as happening is that the Main Folder and the subfolders was beeing created with a Space and the end of the folder such as "FolderName ". The same was happening with the subfolders. I Just add so I delete the last character of the folder I create.:

```
 nameCap="${nameCap%?}"
```